# Efficient way to get a matrix of high and low expressions for multiple variables to be used for simulations

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, matrix, transform

I want to have a matrix including one high (1 sd above average) and low (1 sd below median) expression for each variable out of multiple variables.

In one variant, for each variable I would like to have one high expression, while all other variables are low.

In addition, I would like to have a variant in which all other variables are set to 0 and then there is a high and a low expression for each variable.

I want to use it for model predictions.

For three variables I would already need for variant 1:

```
pred_da <- data.frame(var1 = c(median(da$var1)+1*sd(da$var1), median(da$var1)-1*sd(da$var1), median(da$var1)-1*sd(da$var1)), var2 = c(median(da$var2)-1*sd(da$var2), median(da$var2)+1*sd(da$var2), median(da$var2)-1*sd(da$var2)), var3 = c(median(da$var3)-1*sd(da$var3), median(da$var3)-1*sd(da$var3), median(da$var3)+1*sd(da$var3)))
```

For variant 2 it would be even more...

There should be a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a sample of your data. It makes it a lot easier to provide help.

Comment: I think it's do-able, just that can you do like dput(head(da)) and paste the output as part of your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Adam B.'s solution puts the medians instead of median - sd as results (see code below in reproducible example).

Also, your example code uses *median* +/- sd, while the text defines "high" as 1 sd above *average* (not median), so it is not clear which one you want. I went with median in both cases.

You can achieve the same quite easily with base R by filling a matrix with the "low" expression for each column  and adding the "high" expression in the diagonal:

```r
# data (common to all versions)  
set.seed(1)
da <-
  data.frame(
    ID = 1:10,
    var1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
    var2 = rpois(10, 2),
    var3 = rexp(10, 1),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
varnames <- colnames(da)[-1]

# my version
mat <- data.matrix(da[, -1])
median_da <- apply(mat, 2, median)
sds <- apply(mat, 2, sd)
lower <- median_da - sds
higher <- median_da + sds
res_mat <-
  matrix(
    rep(lower, each = length(varnames)),
    nrow = length(varnames),
    dimnames = list(seq_along(varnames), varnames)
  )
diag(res_mat) <- higher
data.frame(res_mat)
#>         var1       var2       var3
#> 1  1.0371615 -0.4337209 -0.1102957
#> 2 -0.5240104  2.4337209 -0.1102957
#> 3 -0.5240104 -0.4337209  1.3406680

## your version:
pred_da <-
  data.frame(
    var1 = c(
      median(da$var1) + 1 * sd(da$var1),
      median(da$var1) - 1 * sd(da$var1),
      median(da$var1) - 1 * sd(da$var1)
    ),
    var2 = c(
      median(da$var2) - 1 * sd(da$var2),
      median(da$var2) + 1 * sd(da$var2),
      median(da$var2) - 1 * sd(da$var2)
    ),
    var3 = c(
      median(da$var3) - 1 * sd(da$var3),
      median(da$var3) - 1 * sd(da$var3),
      median(da$var3) + 1 * sd(da$var3)
    )
  )

# check for equality of results:
all.equal(data.frame(res_mat), pred_da, check.attributes = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE


# Adam B.'s version:
library(tidyverse)

median_da <- da %>%
  select(- ID) %>%
  mutate_all(~ median(.x)) %>%
  slice(1)

sds <- da %>%
  select(- ID) %>%
  summarise_all(sd)

add_sd <- function(varname, sd) {

  median <- median_da %>%
    pluck(varname)

  median_da %>%
    mutate(!!varname := median + sd)

}

preds_da <- map2(varnames, sds, ~ add_sd(varname = .x, sd = .y)) %>% bind_rows()
preds_da
#>        var1     var2      var3
#> 1 1.0371615 1.000000 0.6151862
#> 2 0.2565755 2.433721 0.6151862
#> 3 0.2565755 1.000000 1.3406680
median_da
#>        var1 var2      var3
#> 1 0.2565755    1 0.6151862
```

Comment: Yes, that works as well, thanks a lot! Indeed, I did not make it clear, sorry.

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot about the "low" observations! The function `add_sd() ` can be easily modified though to output two rows of data, one for variable + sd and another for variable - sd.

Comment: I changed my answer, see below

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a mind-squeezer with nonstandard eval, but I managed to get it to work with my example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

da <- tibble(ID = 1:10, V1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1), V2 = rpois(10, 2), V3 = rexp(10, 1))

varnames <- colnames(da)[-1]

median_da <- da %>%
  select(- ID) %>%
  mutate_all(~ median(.x)) %>%
  slice(1)

sds <- da %>%
  select(- ID) %>%
  summarise_all(sd)

add_sd <- function(varname, sd) {

  median <- median_da %>%
    pluck(varname)

  median_low <- median_da %>%
    mutate(!!varname := median - sd)

  median_high <- median_da %>%
    mutate(!!varname := median + sd)

  median_low %>%
     bind_rows(median_high) 

}

preds_da <- map2(varnames, sds, ~ add_sd(varname = .x, sd = .y)) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: A fantastic piece of code, it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I believe this solution put medians instead of median - sd in the results for "low". See code in answer below for reproducible example.